# How to get runtime access to version number of a running Clojure application?

Tags: clojure, continuous-integration, jenkins, leiningen, continuous-deployment

I have a web service written in Clojure which is [continuously delivered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery). To allow our automated deployment tools to know which version of the codebase has been deployed, the web service should provide a way to query which version it is. The version is declared as part of the project setup in the [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) build tool, like this:

```
(defproject my-web-service "1.2-SNAPSHOT"
  ; ... rest of project.clj
  )
```

The codebase is packaged as a JAR file.

We developers do not want to increment the version number on each commit. Instead, we want it to be incremented automatically whenever a new build is triggered on our [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server (in this case Jenkins). For example, when a version control checkin prompts the forty-second build of this codebase, the version is `1.2.42`.

For any particular JAR that's been built and deployed, I want to allow querying the version number somehow (e.g. with an HTTP request, but that's an implementation detail). The response should include the string `1.2.42`.

How do I make that version number available to the running application?

(Possible duplicate, though it doesn't include the Jenkins aspect: [Embed version string from leiningen project in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235445/embed-version-string-from-leiningen-project-in-application))

Answer (score 21):

One way to access this version number is through the `MANIFEST.MF` file which is stored within the JAR file. This will allow access at runtime, through Java's [`java.lang.Package`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html) class. This requires the following three steps:

1. Passing the Jenkins build number to Leiningen, to incorporate in `project.clj`'s `defproject` declaration.
2. Instructing Leiningen to construct a `MANIFEST.MF` with a value for `Implementation-Version`.
3. Invoking `Package#getImplementationVersion()` to get access to a `String` containing the version number.

### 1 - Getting the Jenkins build number

It is possible to use Jenkins' [environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) to access the build number (nicely named `BUILD_NUMBER`). This is available within a JVM process, using `System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER")`. In this case, the JVM process can be the leiningen `project.clj` script, which is Clojure code which can invoke `(System/getenv "BUILD_NUMBER")`. Following the above example, the String returned would be "42".

### 2 - Setting the version in MANIFEST.MF

When building a JAR, Leiningen will include a `MANIFEST.MF` file by default. It also has a configuration option, which allows setting arbitrary key-value pairs in that file. So when we can access the Jenkins build number in Clojure, we can combine that with the static version declaration to set the `Implementation-Version` in the manifest. The relevant portions of the `project.clj` look like this:

```
(def feature-version "1.2")
(def build-version (or (System/getenv "BUILD_NUMBER") "HANDBUILT"))
(def release-version (str feature-version "." build-version))
(def project-name "my-web-service")

(defproject project-name feature-version
  :uberjar-name ~(str project-name "-" release-version ".jar")
  :manifest {"Implementation-Version" ~release-version}

  ... )
```

It's worth noting a couple of the details in this example. The `(if-let ...)` when defining `build-version` is to allow developers to build the JAR locally, without needing to emulate Jenkins' environment variables. The `:uberjar-name` configuration is to allow creating a JAR file which is named using Maven/Ivy conventions. The resulting file in this example would be `my-web-service-1.2.42.jar`.

With this configuration, when Leiningen is invoked by Jenkins on build number 42, the manifest in the resulting JAR will contain the line "Implementation-Version: 1.2.42".

### 3 - Accessing version at runtime

Now that the version String we want to use is in the manifest file, we can access it using Java standard libraries in Clojure code. The following snippet demonstrates this:

```
(ns version-namespace
  (:gen-class))

(defn implementation-version []
  (-> (eval 'version-namespace) .getPackage .getImplementationVersion))
```

Note here, that in order to invoke `getImplementationVersion()`, we need a `Package` instance, and to get that we need an instance of `java.lang.Class`. Hence we ensure that a Java class is generated from this namespace (the call to `(:gen-class)`) (we can then access the `getPackage` method from that class.

The result of this function is a String, e.g. "1.2.42".

### Caveats

It's worth noting there's a couple of gotchas you may have to worry about, but were acceptable for our use case:

- dynamically setting the version string defined in the `project.clj`'s `(defproject ...)` call may cause some other tools not to work, if they rely on the version being hardcoded
- the semantics of `getImplementationVersion` have been abused slightly. Really the version should be: `pkg.getSpecificationVersion() + "." + pkg.getImplementationVersion()`, but since nothing else reads either of these values, we can get away with just setting the implementation version. Note that doing this correctly would require also adding "Specification-Version" to manifest.

---

With the steps above, my running Clojure application can access a version number which corresponds to the Jenkins build which packaged the code.

Comment: Nice writeup. Two notes: you should use or instead of if-let in project.clj. Also, I'm pretty sure you can read the manifest directly rather than calling .getPackage on a class. Though if you can't, you can still get the class without using eval. If you want to fail gracefully without AOT you could try resolve.

Comment: Thanks for response. Updated to use `or` instead of `if-let`. If easiest way to read manifest is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751033/clojure-program-reading-its-own-manifest-mf I think I'd prefer standard JDK way of getting this specific attribute. Many thanks!