# Getting Runtime Access to Clojure version number

Tags: jar, clojure, manifest

From this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599889/how-to-get-runtime-access-to-version-number-of-a-running-clojure-application?rq=1) I developed the code below.  For now its only purpose (compiled as an uberjar) is to print its version number and exit.

```
; core.clj

(ns clojure-test-vnum.core
   (:gen-class))

(defn implementation-version []
  (-> (eval 'clojure-test-vnum.core) .getPackage .getImplementationVersion))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  ;; work around dangerous default behaviour in Clojure
  (alter-var-root #'*read-eval* (constantly false))

  (println (implementation-version)))



  ;project.clj

  (def version "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT")

  (defproject clojure-test-vnum version
     :manifest {"Implementation-Version" ~version}
     :description "Test to see if I can get a version number from an uberjar." 
     :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
     :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
     :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
     :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]
     :main clojure-test-vnum.core
     :aot [clojure-test-vnum.core])
```

While this code compiles fine, I am getting a ClassNotFoundException at runtime.  The problem seems to be with **(eval 'clojure-test-vnum.core)**.

Following is the full stack trace:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure-test-vnum.core, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0)
     at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6380)
     at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
     at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6623)
     at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6582)
     at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2852)
     at clojure_test_vnum.core$implementation_version.invoke(core.clj:5)
     at clojure_test_vnum.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:14)
     at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
     at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
     at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
     at clojure_test_vnum.core.main(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure-test-vnum.core
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2070)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:6855)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:6818)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:6779)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6343)
    ... 10 more
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to change

```
(eval 'clojure-test-vnum.core)
```

to

```
clojure_test_vnum.core
```

since the generated class will have underscores in its name in place of the hyphens in the name of the Clojure entity it is based on. No `eval` is necessary, the symbol will simply resolve to the class.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I now know how to print the version number from an uberjar.  One thing to note, however, is that the eval indeed does appear to be necessary.  Exceptions are thrown if eval is not used (with and without the ' prefixed to the classname).  It does seem strange to me also that it would be necessary.

Comment: @satch5150: I've tested your code with the emendation suggested in the answer and it works fine. Note that you must omit the quote (`'`) in front of the symbol too. (Otherwise you'd be trying to call `getPackage` on the symbol rather than the class it resolves to.)